# How do we prevent chats from being deleted?

Tags: support, comments, chat

A lot of times comments underneath questions or answers get moved to chat, and then after a set period of time these chats are deleted by a cron job/automatically. Some of these chats will be of interest to future users or for that matter serve as a reference. Can this be looked into ? Is there a policy on chat deletion ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I don't think chat rooms are deleted by the system. They're _frozen_ (meaning you can't say stuff) after a certain period of time, but they're always linkable, searchable, and readable. [Here's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=event&nohide=true&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com) the list of rooms.

Comment: @CDR They are deleted. For e.g. I can't find this chat. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75858/discussion-on-answer-by-s-k-why-do-hindus-believe-steppe-pastoralists-didnt-mig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is criteria of [automatic deletion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) of chatrooms, quoting here:

> ### Will these rooms exist forever?
>
> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. *A room is **considered worth retaining** if it has **more than 15 messages** by at least 2 users.*

So if we go by this rule, the mentioned chatroom in comment, unfortunately has exactly 15 messages, no more no less. Hence it got deleted.

Comment: Then I suggest comments get moved to chat iff the number of messages by at least 2 users exceed 15. Let's not be in a hurry to move comments to chat

Comment: @Carmensandiego In general, moderators get a community flag when the comments exceeds 20 count. So the suggestion; that's already in place. :-)